# How to create a Let's Encrypt certificate on the swisscom application cloud?

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, swisscomdev

Fantastic news, that the swisscom app cloud is now supporting Let's Encrypt. However, following the steps in the [documentation](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide-sc/deploy-apps/certificates.html), I am not able to create the certificate:

> 4. The last step is to actually create the certificate by clicking on the route in the routes sidebar and clicking the lock icon. Then follow the wizard and hit “Create”. This will trigger the creation of an SSL certificate for your route.

I can't for the life of me find this "lock item"... am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you must navigate to the space itself, then open the routes sidebar (way pointer icon in the top right corner of the screen), then click the respective route (the selected one should be highlighted in gray). After that you should be able to see the lock icon right underneath the route.

Can you please let me know if that worked?

Comment: in addition to text description a screenshot how it looks http://i.imgur.com/Q8QLiUo.png

Comment: That's what I tried, but unfortunately only the red trash-can icon (to delete the route) appears.

Comment: Hmm, then it must be a permission issue. Is the parent Org of the Space you are trying to create the certificate in actually owning the respective domain? You can only create certificates in Spaces where the parent Org owns the respective domain used in the route you are trying to create the certificate for.

Comment: You're right! With the new user interface of the developer console, the lock icon now appeared, but if I tried to create the certificate, the following error message appeared: _The requested organization is not the owning organization of the CF private domain matching requested domain [..] or the domain does not exist._. Thanks to your input I found out the problem: I set `myapp.mydomain.ch` (i.e. the full route) as the domain, which I had to correct, so that my **domain** is `mydomain.ch` and the **route** is `myapp.mydomain.ch`. Now it works perfectly. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help. All the best with your apps!

Comment: @karobitsu Thanks for pointing out the issue with using a subdomain, saved me quite some time!